# How to prevent other contributers to modify some files in Git?

Tags: git

I have some personal directories in git for experimentation code, but it also may be interesting to others to see. For example directories `/personA` and `/personB`. How can I achieve the following:

- each person can modify and commit changes in his personal directory as usual
- everyone can see all directories
- however, no one should be able to push changes in the other persons directory (it can be a "soft" solution to prevent when this happens by accident)

The other person's directory could be read-only, or alternatively changes there will always be overwritten by a consequent `git pull`.

Comment: Git will not have any way to prevent this, except that you can add githooks on the shared server side to detect this. However, not all git hosting systems allow you to add githooks on their servers, so it depends on where your shared hosting is.

Comment: On each local client, you can't do anything. At most you can, as I said in my other comment, prevent the push operation to complete.

Comment: Note that in Git, nobody ever modifies any files. Instead, people *add new commits* (or sometimes make existing ones un-find-able). The new commits have new and different snapshots. You can call "snapshot 123 has a different copy of file foo than snapshot 122 did" a "modification" of file foo, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You may be able to achieve your goal, but it will be SCM tool dependent.

As mentioned in the comments, Git by itself does not enforce rules as you have described; it's up to maintainer of the *copy* of the repo to control those types of rules. Each developer who clones a repo becomes the maintainer of their own copy of a repo, and so you cannot control what they do with their own repo. However, if you control a repo on a server (e.g. GitHub, GitLab, AzureDevops, BitBucket, etc.) you can enforce some type of security depending on what the tools offer. Sometimes you can extend the default security configuration options with server side hooks or additional status checks and custom policies.

Regarding this goal:

> ...no one should be able to push changes in the other persons directory

Although it may be possible to achieve this with server side settings and custom hooks, note that this type of block is not typical (in my experience). Instead, it's more common to lock down specific shared branches with polices that prevent merging into those branches unless certain conditions are met. When shared branches are locked down in this way, it's common that no one can push to them directly, and a Pull Request is used to merge in changes from another branch. So, the typical scenario would be that anyone could push any kind of change to their own branch, but the policy would enforce that only certain people can modify specific files on the shared branch(es) and so the PR would be blocked if those files are included in the branch to be merged in. Note your goal is still met, but the block happens at "merging into shared branches" rather than at "push".

Comment: Here I use "SCM tool" to mean "Source Control Management tool". I think "VCS tool" ("Version Control System tool") may be equally common. In the context of Git these would be tools like GitHub, GitLab, AzureDevops, BitBucket, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this, because if person have access to git repository, person can modify all files in repository

Comment: Please write your responses with good English and more level of detail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).